# Where are the "manage" custom settings in the Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, customsetting

### I know that a custom setting is a custom object in the metadata api, but I can't find where the options you see when you press *Manage* are in the metadata API.

I have a custom setting, let's call it `MyCustom_settings__c`, in my org. In the GUI when I click on `Manage` I see two fields, `My Subtype One` and `My Subtype Two`. But when I `grep` through the metadata I retrieved from the metadata API, I can't find them anywhere.

I'm also not totally sure what those fields are called, so I'm not sure how to search for them online.

### Where do I find those things in the metadata api? And what should I call them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those items listed after clicking 'Manage' are records of your custom setting, and as such they are data rather than metadata. You can retrieve them with the Data Loader, REST API, or any other source by which you'd normally retrieve Accounts or Contacts.

Custom Metadata records *are* available in the Metadata API, but Custom Settings records are not. This is one reason why Custom Metadata is recommended over List Custom Settings, although Hierarchy Custom Settings still provide additional functionality.

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding: the settings metadata that I see (e.g. `MyCustom_settings__c.object`) are basically a type of setting, and then the records I see when I click Manage are instances of it, just like Bob Smith is an instance of Contact?

Comment: Entirely correct!